# How to assign output bin on HP4730?

Tags: printer, settings

We have an application that prints batches of invoices and when two users print same time, their jobs get interspersed because the application actually generates a separate job for each invoice.

The HP4730 has a bin for phocopies/fax and the bulk bin.

A proposal was to create a separate printer definition for each user, and somehow map their output to a different bin to keep their jobs "together".

However, we can't see any setting to control this on the printer properties.

Does anyone know if thats possible?

To make it more interesting, this is within Citrix...

Help!

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar fo a clinet.  It involved adding a new printer for the specific job.  This way the printer appears as Jim's Duplex Staped HP XXXX.  The settings are configured on that "printer" and the user prints to that when they want a duplex job that is stapled.  Should work to assign bin.  User just picks the correct one